# Agrupar objeto no javascript por categoria

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Possuo um objeto no JS com informações de locais (Cinema, Museu, etc..) que vou utilizar para popular no meu sistema.
Exemplo:

```
    var places = {
        "type": "ABC",
        "features": [ 
            {
                "type": "AB",
                "properties": {
                    "title": "Text 1",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum 1",
                    "category": "Museu"
                },
                "optional": {
                    "type": "ZX",
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "AB",
                "properties": {
                    "title": "Text 2",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum 2",
                    "category": "Museu"
                },
                "optional": {
                    "type": "ZX",
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "AB",
                "properties": {
                    "title": "Text 3",
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum 3",
                    "category": "Hotel"
                },
                "optional": {
                    "type": "ZX",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Porém agora preciso quebrar ele em um objeto dividindo por categoria, basicamente ficando dessa forma:

```
    var variavel = {
        {
            category: "Museu",
            places: {
                type: "ABC",
                features: [ 
                    {
                        "type": "AB",
                        "properties": {
                            "title": "Text 1",
                            "description": "Lorem ipsum 1",
                            "category": "Museu"
                        },
                        "optional": {
                            "type": "ZX",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AB",
                        "properties": {
                            "title": "Text 2",
                            "description": "Lorem ipsum 2",
                            "category": "Museu"
                        },
                        "optional": {
                            "type": "ZX",
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            category: "Hotel",
            places: {
                type: "ABC",
                features: [ 
                    {
                        "type": "AB",
                        "properties": {
                            "title": "Text 3",
                            "description": "Lorem ipsum 3",
                            "category": "Hotel"
                        },
                        "optional": {
                            "type": "ZX",
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Qual a melhor forma de obter esse resultado? 
Nesse projeto não há ES6.

Comment: O que vc já tentou fazer?

Comment: Já tem exemplos de muitas respostas por aqui com ES6, utilizando `reduce`, `map`, `findIndex` entre outros. Tem que usar a mesma lógica e transformar essas funções nos respetivos laços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara eu desenvolvi meu raciocínio em cima do ES6, ou seja, caso queira implementar da maneira que fiz basta converter o código pra ES5 (Existem várias métodos de fazer isso de forma bem simples)..

Segue abaixo a maneira que pensei para resolver o problema

** a funcao recebe como parametro uma variavel 'data' que representa a estrutura de dados que voce mostrou na sua pergunta

```
function filterPlacesByCategory( data ){
    const categories = getAllCategories()
    const filteredData = breakAndBuildTheNewStructure()
    return filteredData

    function getAllCategories(){
        // pega todas as categorias
        const allCategories = data.features.map((item)=>{
            return item.properties.category
        })
        // remove as categorias repetidas
        const categoriesWithoutRepeatData = allCategories.filter(function(item, index, self) {
            return self.indexOf(item) == index;
        })

        return categoriesWithoutRepeatData
    }

    function breakAndBuildTheNewStructure(){
        return categories.map((category)=>{
            // para cada categoria ele verifica quais lugares tem aquela categoria e os retorna
            const placesWithCorrespondentCategory = places.features.filter((item)=>{
                return item.properties.category == category
            })
            // reconstroi a base dos dados ja filtrados
            return {
                "category": category,
                "places": placesWithCorrespondentCategory
            }

        })
    }
}
```